# How do I iterate through BigQuery API results in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm working on some automated queries in Google Apps Script.  I have a result data set of 300k+ results but I can only obtain the first 30k.  How can I modify this code so that it iterates through all of the query results to return all 300k records?  I want to return everything into the variable "rows".

EDIT for more info: I have tried BQ API methods like getNextPage() and iterateAll() but I'm not able to call these on queryResults.  I've looked through Stack Overflow and there isn't much documentation for this. This current script hangs on the while(queryResults.pagetoken) loop currently and cannot output all 300k results.

```
var request = {
    query: query,
    "useLegacySql": false
    
  };
    Logger.log(request);
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
    Logger.log(jobId);
  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
   Logger.log(queryResults.pageToken);
  
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
    Logger.log('row check:');
    Logger.log(queryResults.totalRows);
    Logger.log(queryResults.rows.length);
  }
```

Comment: please provide more information, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there anything specific I could add?  I'm not sure what else to say, I just need to know how to iterate through BigQuery API results in Google Apps Scripts

Comment: what have you tried? what has or hasn't worked? what resources have you used? what research have you done and where did it lead you? what errors have you encountered?

Comment: basically more background on the issue

Comment: Is this better?  This should just be clarification on an iteration method for the getQueryResults object.

Comment: have You considered outputting the results in batches? get 30K 10 times If it seems like that's what it can handle

Comment: Hi ! When running your script do you enconter any errors? How long does it approximately take on running? Have you checked [Apps Script limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)? Thanks ! :D